# Empty string passed to constructor via Autofac instead of expected value

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm new to autofac, so sorry if i'm asking a dumb question.
I'm having trouble passing an argument to a constructor

I've got the following Interface and class:

```
interface IMyService
{
    string GetVersion();
}

class MyService : webService, IMyService
{
    public MyService(string serverPath)
        : base(serverPath){}

    public string GetVersion() { return "1.0"; }
}
```

This is how i'm setting things up:

```
public static class AutofacManager
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<string>();
        builder.Register<MyService>((c, p) => new MyService(c.Resolve<string>(p))).As<IMyService>();
        Container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

and i'm using the object like this:

```
var ws = Container.Resolve<IMyService>(Autofac.TypedParameter.From<string>(url));
var ver = ws.GetVersion();
```

The problem is that an empty string is passed to the constructor. I expected it to pass the url varialbe.

Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first thing is you try to register the string type, which is not needed (you can remove that lineà.

You can modify your delegate to match the following:

```
builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
    var url = p.Named<string>("url");
    return new MyService(url);
}).As<IMyService>();
```

You add a named parameter so you can specify url at resolve time.

The As will make sure to register as interface (otherwise you register concrete class).

Then to Resolve your object:

```
string MyUrl = "";
var ws = Container.Resolve<IMyService>(new NamedParameter("url", MyUrl));
```

EDIT: Instead of having to resolve with url everytime, you can also allow to set url at register time, eg:

```
string MyUrl = "hello";
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().
WithParameter(new NamedParameter("serverPath",MyUrl)).As<IMyService>();
```

Then, you can resolve as:

```
var ws = Container.Resolve<IMyService>();
```

Comment: Nice explanation and thanks for the tip explaining how I can set the url at register time. That's not what I want to do this time, but I can see that I might in the future.

Comment: No problem, please note that you can register with default and override with resolve too (that also works).